# htaccess [b] tag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This line of code works fine on my old server:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?promo=$1 [L,B]
```

But on the new server, i figured out that the 'B' at the end causes error 500, thus NOTHING works

So i have to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?promo=$1 [L]
```

The thing is that I really need that B. Does anyone know whats going on here? 
Is this an apache version thing or something?

Also, what is the term for this feature? I think its called a B flag, but im not 100% sure about that.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: From the docs: 'B' Escape Backreferences http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: `[L,B]` should be fine (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags). Is the 500 coming from index.php or mod_rewrite?

Comment: @scuzzy - thanks, i checked it out. Now i know wheres its documented - which is great. But it doesn't offer me any insights as to why its not working

Comment: @mu - yeh it was fine on the old server. Bugger that it stopped on this new server. The 500 is caused by the B in the htaccess. Index.php has no issues. I am trying to upgrade apache from ver 2 to ver 2.2, hoping itll fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[B] didn't get added to Apache until 2.2.7.  So if you are only upgrading from 2 to 2.2.x where x < 7, then that'd explain things.